# How to edit PUMA560 proto file in webots

Tags: proto, webots

I'm new to webots and want to design simulation using PUMA560. In there I need to change the gripper shapes and size. But when I replace the existing gripper with a new solid box shape, suddenly everything went disappear. 
How can I edit the proto file?

I tried updating the gripper slot by using the Pioneer3 gripper. but still, the previous gripper exist. How can I remove it and combine the existing controller to the new gripper?

Answer (score 3):

As a first step I would recommend to un-prototize the robot to edit it, this way it will be much simpler to edit the robot definition directly using the GUI of Webots in the scene-tree.

To un-prototize a robot in Webots you simply have to right click on the node and then select 'Convert to Base Node(s)'.

Once you are happy with the result of the non-proto version you can try to migrate your changes to the PROTO file, here is a tutorial explaining how to create a PROTO file:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-7-your-first-proto